# Multiple result from the Query which having a single record

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to fetch multiple result from the query even though if it has single record stored in DB. For eg.

```
select name from stud where name in ('ABC','DEF','ABC')
```

This query gives me result

```
+------+
| Name |
+------+
| ABC  |
| DEF  |
+------+
```

But I want this query to give me result like this

```
+------+
| Name |
+------+
| ABC  |
| DEF  |
| ABC  |
+------+
```

Is it possible to do so. If it is then how should I modify my query

Comment: Create a temp table (or similar) with the ('ABC','DEF','ABC'). Do a reversed table order query.

Comment: why you need this kind of answer?

Comment: Because I'm adding a Equipment and on every order a cust can add single equipment of the same type so the logic is written in a way that it always fetch Equipment data from the DB, but as per new requirement cust can request multiple Equipment of same type, I've tried to using Hash Map since the functionality is working from java, but I dont want to change a large chunk of code

Answer (score 0):

Following the @jarlh suggestion:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 'ABC' AS name UNION ALL
    SELECT 'DEF' UNION ALL
    SELECT 'ABC'
)

SELECT t.name
FROM cte t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stud s WHERE s.name = t.name);
```

The exists logic ensures that each name in the CTE only appears once, even if that name should match multiple times to the student table.

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer is very much on track.  But, you seem to care about the ordering of the result set.  If so,  you should have an explicit `ORDER BY`:

```
WITH cte AS (
      SELECT 'ABC' AS name, 1 as ord UNION ALL
      SELECT 'DEF', 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 'ABC', 3
     )
SELECT t.name
FROM cte t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM stud s WHERE s.name = t.name)
ORDER BY ord;
```